# How do i get the Admins list for AAD Tenant by passing Tenant ID?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need the Tenant admins information to work on a migration project, Is there any way to fetch the admin information by Tenant ID? thanks.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Azure AD powershell module:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to get  directory role by name like `Application Administrator`.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}
Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId
```

[image]

And you could use [`Get-AzureADDirectoryRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Get-AzureADDirectoryRole?view=azureadps-2.0) to get all directory roles.

Comment: There are also Microsoft Graph APIs for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryrole?view=graph-rest-v1.0